# Kusto cannot project a value into a user defined function

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query in our domain which I can not get it to work. I used datatable to mimic my issue.
I'm trying to use a projected value in an userdefined function.

```
// this works
let f = (a:int) {
    datatable (b:string, d:int) ["2015-12-31", 1, "2016-12-30", 2, "2014-01-05", 3]
    | as dataset
    | where d == a
    | project b;
};
datatable (d:int) [1, 2, 3]
| as dataset
| project toscalar(f(2))

// this doesnt work, why is the 'd' not used (projected) in function q. 
// if I add toscalar to the project it also doesnt work
let f = (a:int) {
    datatable (b:string, d:int) ["2015-12-31", 1, "2016-12-30", 2, "2014-01-05", 3]
    | as dataset
    | where d == a
    | project b;
};
datatable (d:int) [1, 2, 3]
| as dataset
| project toscalar(f(d))
```

What am I missing here, I expect the '| project' use the function (f) for each result.

here the 2 queries to tinker with.

[first query](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WOQQ6CMBBF9016hx9WJaGhLeICw0mMiwJFUAKmbcJCvbsFQtSZzOZl5s1PU%2Fiud5gne3eUDMajRQmmi370MZ6UIFSjfehqMGBV4bztx2uCZls5R0rInEvFMxklkAkWcFyBCEBt4MCF5CIPILts0he0W83O%2BJ3MnbEGDcoSemcPO91M7VGdKHmH%2BQmzR5Drm0X8L%2F0e%2B8nVetCWtUzFMSUfn8L5y%2FgAAAA%3D&timespan=P1D)

[second query](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA1WQ0UrEMBBF3wv9h8u%2BbAqtbbquDyv9AL9BfEibqY2WRJNZiqj%2FbrY1uGYIhMPMmUvqGjyZAO0oWMbi%2FGuJZfpAZDwR9noP6xjnQBrizbsXGph0AWMxnu3Axlm83yDP6hpmxAOU1mAXBjUrHx%2Br5XcOhqHm4K635dlMjBEdhDoZywU%2B8wzxaMWx%2Bpkg%2BlNgb%2BxzCb21PO7aRh4r2VYHuSshS1zA3QqaCNoN3FaNrJpjBIenTfoFFVZzIE5kmcgTNLoOKrEUuL%2FPs%2B94r8KkCHJdcxH%2Fl%2F4Np18Qo9BFkf0ALaq%2FrmsBAAA%3D&timespan=P1D)

thanks

Comment: This is the restriction of user-defined function, the column can not be used as the parameter of user-defined function. You can take a look at the restrctions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions-on-the-use-of-user-defined-functions)

Comment: The comment is not correct. The column value can be sent to the user-defined-function. The reason that example does not work is using 'toscalar()' with row-context (meaning that toscalar() cannot be invoked for-each row-value).

Comment: @AlexanderSloutsky, you're right. I just wanted to explain it more simpler, but gave an incorrect explanation, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the restriction of user-defined function, toscalar() cannot be invoked for-each row-value. You can take a look at the restrctions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions-on-the-use-of-user-defined-functions).

Here is a workaround, which can achieve your goal(You can also use this [query link](https://portal.loganalytics.io/Demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OwQ6CMBBE7yT%2Bw4RTm9CkBfGA8S%2B4GQ9FiqmS1kDjRf13l1YS9jZvdndmNAEDTmBtw%2FrGusA53rsMNCNZQXejUeT3OugowLpmDpN1twLpAOe8lKoWqhSVyguoAgs4RCAJlAnshVRC1gSqS0r4QM%2Fx82zCMaF2de7eOrCkaP5FkubwDv26%2BZz83VwDOpD9pT%2BbrmtDFVssudvMRVn38g%2BDgfHsB1nkpzQMAQAA&timespan=P1D) to run it directly):

```
let f = (T:(d:int)) {
    let table1 = datatable (b:string, d:int) ["2015-12-31", 1, "2016-12-30", 2, "2014-01-05", 3]
    | as dataset;
    T
    | join (
       table1 
    ) on d
    | project b  
};

datatable (d:int) [1, 2, 3]
| as dataset
| invoke f()
```

Test result as below:

[image]

Comment: Hello, if the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to achieve this (without join) is to create a dynamic map (property bag) using toscalar() and then use it as lookup dictionary.

```
let f = (a:int) {
    let _lookup = toscalar 
    (
        datatable (b:string, d:int) ["2015-12-31", 1, "2016-12-30", 2, "2014-01-05", 3]
        | extend p = pack(tostring(d), b)
        | summarize make_bag(p)
     );
    _lookup[tostring(a)]
};
datatable (d:int) [1, 2, 3]
| project result=f(d)
```

Comment: Clever approach :) How does it perform for large dataset comparing to `JOIN`?

Comment: This approach works well when you have static data sets with few hundreds of items. If data set grows beyond that and still below 1M values - it is (perf-wise) better to use join with "broadcast" hint or "lookup" operator.  If the data sets goes beyond that - shuffle join approach comes to rescue. (Google: "kusto lookup", "kusto broadcast join", "kusto shuffle join" - for more details)