# Joining two data sets w/o equality operator

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I've included my sample query below.

What I am trying to accomplish is joining these two tables, w/o an equality operator.

.

For Example, I have a table, which sorts the actual performance of each disk - Disks_Summary

| Computer | Disk | GB_Used | IOPS | Throughput |

| dev |   c | 100 | 120 | 4 |

.

Then I have a table of the SKUs and performance of each disk from Azure - Azure_Disk_Options

| SKU | Capacity_Limit | Price_per_month | IOPS_Limit | Throughput_Limit | 
| P2 | 8 | 0.66 | 120 | 25 |

So what I am trying to accomplish, is to "map" Disk_Summary actual performance into the appropriate class of disk in Azure_Disk_Options.

My thought was something like this

```
| where 
    IOPS < IOPS_Limit and Capacity < Capacity_Limit and Throughput < Throughput_Limit 
| summarize min(Price_per_month)
```

I was using this answer for reference but I was running into limitations around user-defined functions 
[Kusto cannot project a value into a user defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703226/kusto-cannot-project-a-value-into-a-user-defined-function)

[sample query](https://portal.azure.com#@d9df5011-1cb7-430d-a4c2-912741e161ab/blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade/resourceId/%2FDemo/source/LogsBlade.AnalyticsShareLinkToQuery/q/H4sIAAAAAAAAA9WYXW%252FbNhSG7w34Pwi5kgGNISnqK9kGtGkWDGvRIF6xi6IQFJtLtNiSJ9HJ0nb%252FfYeUZFE0laTAhmQKAllHL88H%252BZCidHj4XMd00v2vuHBqkVXC%252BcHJrkqXsOXsuDHzYgnGorxzO4vI1%252FysyvIC7OT6uPfybIUc6jk0Sb76vK14ep6%252Byeub9P1G5GVRQ77TyTIT8He54o47%252F%252BXDUS2qvLjynJNsky1ycZ%252B%252Bzde5OFqV0nhe5QuebniVrstCXB8t%252BSJfZyvP%252Bfn9%252BXyg%252FPW6KrdX15ut0Myz6cSB42NzksfBOTnwHOY5GPm%252B5xCKPYcGni6gIIilIAztAh8ERN5DPrUrGCjkvQDR2K4IQRFCGgQjSuAuA0mABxKCZRzlIEERkfexbGCoggPpHNLxY4RlPkTJzKKks4DA%252FchHFE7UVzIjpq9iYioz8wNEIhVVpm%252BEZVJIMYtl8AThAByr%252FKjhMZBChhNIkCUBCqIxYSiFMUkgt4SFCMu6QxU7MGJHKsnQj2WWMaYIh%252BqH1EaG1xiroYhCcOeHmCFCVDFSm%252Bz8fppOjk1yT18auac7cklghep0R66P7YKOXGB7RNGRSxEbUXTkMhRjK7inPbiJiqOGOzQ0O2wBbjoi6qEFttmISEM2ClVONpXGKwn80bQ0Wn0cjSamsRoSplKjCik2RPV0gCqlscqP4cblUKqTSlkQqRxDDWobpPOXBum8A4iggFk7b94B5CNM7IoeoADFyYimB4iopdwm6gGiBEWhXaQBxDBKRlQaQFGE4pGAGj%252BE%252BcgfcabxQ0OKiFpupc4fQjHX%252BWEJ9CntSDMWxbmOTwKEB4GmbIU9QfsPap2j9OLVb4ol2zN8Ovnq1LzKs1X%252BmTvyiv8l5B5lR9i83cdsKn7rDrmbaXrF2EDbU6frNPQGahNJ1WZbQI6QlduUbFvKmzvDIhrLtxUyaPNIMQPtNxQ0XtP8%252F1vTkxjU%252BDPRHCXQWM7ABQQvlq5hh4kxe4jbPP%252FdNYw%252FOtgzhPAUHaVZetAMqnV%252FbbS0dJ1sv2dWXkyr4euivCu260teqdrv0ubCVZJNVf7BF%252BK7ipfVEhQ77WBVkKMxnZxxkWqdr7vtu%252BaC%252F7nNK77mhajbx4Qq0mLX0t6726L0pTmJsl5kq6xy%252B8Wth34f%252BbHjq3N3zatuGjx2WEtyvjcemk%252FzlcEwPE2511kQsZ9h%252F3a0kSGAmOYcfaxnRblxiHN5vzffsnrxWNsWQh0%252BXdCy8Pdgq7OHY79E%252FMcwykNmkK7K8ma7UWuSnm4H69Dq7nfCU%252FDdTWKo6Eaun3ByIYLawLm7Dpt56k6arVbubLbv5vDQ5qiR24LW2%252FU6q%252BRKepldgXqd3fAUfrqy2Zj%252F22y1zYRqkm4LlSn8nFkHszuOh5dtn37cVTi25tjH2DK8oyM7m31yTLCe%252F5OJ5ZuJKnyuBuTe3MyflGuoi1e7Hf2bKr%252Fl6VsudKPslH4b3%252FdHbzt7nX6o%252BbIzWPbwS34Le8mDE7nh9VHCAvnCyHDU7pL3lT9JJWpeLLHazBo6wWvRuUxQFEkhfUDXOJSfKaRDS2BYRpadQxKiIFEu%252FegBqfQJ72qEJcqr3Cc3m%252F72GN0jvxRAmv8NjLNw7Aui2365CeSrOwysjpPaNHVTfTgTJTPys2NxrzYtxrT1tEmVF%252Bm71620N5sNWsJaXXuliS7v%252B98d1b3F07nWtjbwMgseRwpvgzT8D9YBlTIE%252FwdgbpGE5RUAAA%253D%253D/timespan/P1D)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use toscalar() with row-context as documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#user-defined-functions-usage-restrictions

The way to solve your scenario - is to use cross-join and filter after the join:

```
let start = ago(14d);
let end = now();
let timeGrain = 1h;
let Azure_P_Disk_Options = 
datatable (SKU:string, Capacity_Limit:long, Price_per_month:decimal, IOPS_Limit:long, Throughput_Limit:long)
    [
        "P1", 4, 0.33, 120, 25,
        "P2", 8, 0.66, 120, 25,
        "P3", 16, 1.32, 120, 25,
        "P4", 32, 5.28, 120, 25,
        "P6", 64, 10.21, 240, 50,
        "P10", 128, 19.71, 500, 100,
        "P15", 256, 38.02, 1100, 125,
        "P20", 512, 73.22, 2300, 150,
        "P30", 1024, 135.17, 5000, 200,
        "P40", 2048, 259.05, 7500, 250,
        "P50", 4096, 495.57, 7500, 250,
        "P60", 8192, 946.08, 16000, 500,
        "P70", 16384, 1802.06, 18000, 750,
        "P80", 32768, 3604.11, 20000, 900,
    ]
;
//
let Azure_E_Disk_Options = 
datatable (SKU:string, Capacity_Limit:long, Price_per_month:decimal, IOPS_Limit:long, Throughput_Limit:long)
    [
        "E1", 4, 0.15, 120, 25,
        "E2", 8, 0.30, 120, 25,
        "E3", 16, 0.60, 120, 25,
        "E4", 32, 2.40, 120, 25,
        "E6", 64, 4.80, 240, 50,
        "E10", 128, 9.60, 500, 60,
        "E15", 256, 19.20, 500, 60,
        "E20", 512, 38.40, 500, 60,
        "E30", 1024, 76.80, 500, 60,
        "E40", 2048, 153.60, 500, 60,
        "E50", 4096, 307.20, 500, 60,
        "E60", 8192, 614.40, 2000, 400,
        "E70", 16384, 1228.80, 4000, 600,
        "E80", 32768, 2457.60, 6000, 750,
]
;
//
let Azure_S_Disk_Options = 
datatable (SKU:string, Capacity_Limit:long, Price_per_month:decimal, IOPS_Limit:long, Throughput_Limit:long)
    [
        "S4", 32, 1.54, 500, 60,
        "S6", 64, 3.01, 500, 60,
        "S10", 128, 5.89, 500, 60,
        "S15", 256, 11.33, 500, 60,
        "S20", 512, 21.76, 500, 60,
        "S30", 1024, 40.96, 500, 60,
        "S40", 2048, 77.83, 500, 60,
        "S50", 4096, 143.36, 500, 60,
        "S60", 8192, 262.14, 1300, 300,
        "S70", 16384, 491.52, 2000, 500,
        "S80", 32768, 953.55, 2000, 500
     ]
;
//
let Azure_Disk_Options_RAW = 
Azure_P_Disk_Options
| serialize 
| extend Capacity_Start = prev(Capacity_Limit)
| extend IOPS_Start = prev(IOPS_Limit)
| extend Throughput_Start = prev(Throughput_Limit)
| union 
(
    Azure_E_Disk_Options
    | serialize 
    | extend Capacity_Start = prev(Capacity_Limit)
    | extend IOPS_Start = prev(IOPS_Limit)
    | extend Throughput_Start = prev(Throughput_Limit)
)
| union 
(
    Azure_S_Disk_Options
    | serialize 
    | extend Capacity_Start = prev(Capacity_Limit)
    | extend IOPS_Start = prev(IOPS_Limit)
    | extend Throughput_Start = prev(Throughput_Limit)
);
//
let Azure_Disk_Options = 
Azure_Disk_Options_RAW
| serialize 
| extend Price_per_month = round(Price_per_month, 2)
| extend Capacity_Start = iif(Capacity_Start > 0, Capacity_Start, 0)
| extend IOPS_Start = iif(IOPS_Start > 0, IOPS_Start, 0)
| extend Throughput_Start = iif(Throughput_Start > 0, Throughput_Start, 0)
| extend Rownumber = row_number()
| project-reorder Rownumber
;
//
let Disk_Summary = 
datatable (Computer:string, Drive_Letter:string, IOPS:decimal, Throughput:decimal, GB_Used:decimal)
    [
        "dev", "C", 23.945, 0.407, 1024,
        "dev", "F", 2.16, 0.014, 1024,
        "test", "C", 9.77, 0.24, 1024,
        "test", "F", 2.22, 0.017, 1024,
        "prod", "C", 16.597, 0.377, 1024,
        "prod", "F", 14.149, 0.068, 1024,        
     ]
;
Disk_Summary
| summarize IOPS = any(IOPS) ,Throughput_in_MB = any(Throughput) ,GB_Used = any(GB_Used) by Computer, Drive_Letter
| extend _key = 1
| join kind=inner (Azure_Disk_Options_RAW | extend _key=1) on _key
| where GB_Used < Capacity_Limit and IOPS < IOPS_Limit and Throughput_in_MB < Throughput_Limit
| summarize arg_min(Price_per_month, *) by Computer, Drive_Letter
| project-away _key, _key1
```